# Zendesk SSO error - Please use one of the options below to sign in to Zendesk

Tags: zendesk

I integrated the zendesk Single Sign On using JWT several months ago and experienced no issues with customer authentication until this week.  Our support team started receiving complaints from some of our customers this week where users that had logged in (authenticated) with our web app but could not access the Zendesk knowledge base.  The issue seems at this point to be related to new user accounts.

I am getting the following error message appended to the URL on zendesk authentication failure:

kind=error&message=Please+use+one+of+the+options+below+to+sign+in+to+Zendesk.

Has anyone run into this issue or know what this error indicates?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to this:

> If your Zendesk is closed or restricted, and a user tries to sign in
> with a different email than the one in Zendesk Support, their request
> will be rejected (see [Enabling social and business single sign-on](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408885847962) )

Answer (score 0):

The original discussion was removed from zendesk site for some weird reason:
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QjwCf_sEY4oJ:https://support.zendesk.com/hc/es/community/posts/115008094888-Zendesk-SSO-error-Please-use-one-of-the-options-below-to-sign-in-to-Zendesk+&cd=1&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru

> I actually solved this for our installation last night. I finally realised what I was doing wrong. I had only turned on SSO for end-users so when I tired to test it, as an agent, it was showing this error. So turning on SSO also for agents solved this.

> Thanks for sharing, Greg! That's a good tip.

> Yes, thanks Greg! that resolved my issue with this error as well!

> Thanks for sharing your resolution, Greg! Arlen, I'm glad you got it working!